# how to find the node which has child node while parsing XML file using DOM parser in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

I want to parse a xml document and convert into json. 
I'm facing problem in finding which node has child and which has not.

*Example :*

```
<Bank>
    <Account>
        <Id>1001</Id>
        <Name>Jack Robinson</Name>
       <Amt>10000</Amt>
    </Account>
</Bank>
```

In this xml file, I want to find first Bank node has a child element i.e. Account , same like Account node has child node i.e. Id,Name,Amt.
But Id, Name and Amt node does not have any childs, so I want to find like this which node has child child and which node has not?

I'm trying with **node.hasChildNodes()** method but it will return true for each node.

Please help me to solve this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**node.hasChildNodes()** returns true because it finds the empty text element as a child.
So in your case **Bank** has child **empty text** and then **Account**.
A solution is to remove the formatting elements from the XML, and then parse it.
You can check if a node is an **empty text** or an element node by using **node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE**.

Comment: yes right. can you guide me to how to remove xml whitespaces?

Comment: You can call **node.normalize()** before testing for child nodes. Another solution would be to call **node.getChildNodes()** and to check if any of the returned nodes is of type Node.ELEMENT_NODE. Either cases work.

Comment: Thanks bro. It's working great. only one problem I'm facing in that is how to identify the element is ending i.e. in this case </Account> is end tag and I want to identify that end tag so that I can write json end object... Give me any hint or any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
NodeList iDNodes = (Account).getElementsByTagName("Id");
int lengthofID = value1Nodes.getLength();

if(lengthofID > 0){
 //..proceed
}
```

alternatively similar is

```
doc.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().getLength();
```

Comment: **getElementByTagName** method returns NodeList of all the elements with a given name and I don't want this. I want to identify for the child.

Comment: `child` is also a `Element` in its Node. Perhaps the second example will help `doc.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().getLength();`